# Appending Elements to a List Creates List of List in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am parsing each element of a list one by one.

```
def List1 = (String[]) Data[2].split(',')
```

Part of this list gives me a list with elements that contain a delimiter `!`.

```
List1 = [TEST1!01.01.01, TEST2!02.02.02]
```

I tried to iterate each element of this list and obtain a comma separated list.

```
          def List2 = []
          List1.each { List2.add(it.split('!'))}
```

However, the result was a list of list.

```
[[TEST1, 01.01.01], [TEST2, 02.02.02]]
```

Instead of `[TEST1, 01.01.01, TEST2, 02.02.02]`.

How do I avoid this and obtain a list as shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split()` returns a list. That is the reason why I got a list of list. I found that `split()` can carry process multiple delimiters as well when applied with an operator.
The following returns the desired output.

```
def List1 = (String[]) Data[2].split(',|!')
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```groovy
def list1 = ['TEST1!01.01.01', 'TEST2!02.02.02']
println list1.collect{it.split('!')}.flatten()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `List2.add(it.split('!'))`, you are adding list to `List2` instead of single string because `.split()` creates a list from string.

You should firstly create list by using `.split()` and than add each member of list to `List2`.

Here is solution:

```
def List1 = ["TEST1!01.01.01", "TEST2!02.02.02"]

​def List2 = []          

List1.each { List1member ->
    def subList = List1member.split('!')
    subList.each { subListMember ->
        List2.add(subListMember)
    } 
}

println(List2)​
```